# How to open a .lbk file with a .exe with php?

Tags: php, file, exec

I have a .exe file that when I drag and drop a .lbk file on it is generated another file with .txt extension.

When I try to open this .exe file, is opened a cmd window.

So, I want to make this conversion but within webpage via php script if possible. The .exe file will be in server/root folder.

This .exe file is used to convert .lbk files into .txt files.

How can I do this ?

Comment: I don't understand it correctly, you are cloning a file and changing the extension? Is the EXE method required or just an example?

Comment: Use [`exec()`](http://php.net/exec) for runnng commands, and [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) for the filenames.

Comment: This .exe file is used to convert .lbk files into .txt files. And i need to do this procedure automatically.